# How separate Route config from startup in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

i want to separate Route config from startup in asp.net core?
by default in .net core:

```
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: How do you mean "separate"? Do you mean you want to add and delete routes at runtime, **or** just that you want your route configuration to be in its own file?

Comment: i want to separate route config file from startup class

Comment: OK then amir's answer is correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use below code:

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static IRouteBuilder Use(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
    {
        //eg sample for defining Custom route
        //routeBuilder.MapRoute("blog", "blog",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

        routeBuilder.MapRoute(name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        return routeBuilder;
    }
}
```

and in startup and Configure method:

```
app.UseMvc(c => RouteConfig.Use(c));
```